# Error https 500 for send email using mb_language PHP on ec2 AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2

now im doing code for send email. this is a simple send email code. i used fresh setup EC2 on AWS to run this code.

for the setup the EC2 server. i run these commend :

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y httpd24 php72 mysql57-server php72-mysqlnd
sudo service httpd start
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

following this url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

this is very simple project for send email. i use 2 file for this

- index.php (contain form)
- email.php (contain send email code)

heres is my code on my email.php file for sending the email

```
<?php

mb_language("Japanese");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$to = 'receivee@gmail.com';
$subject = 'send email。';
$subject = mb_convert_encoding($subject, "ISO-2022-JP", "UTF-8,EUC-JP,auto");
$message = "氏名（漢字）：
            {$_POST['name']} 
            メールアドレス：
            {$_POST['email']} 
            お問い合わせ内容：
            {$_POST['message']}";

$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, "ISO-2022-JP", "UTF-8,EUC-JP,auto");
$headers = "From: " .mb_encode_mimeheader("ease") ."<receive@gmail.com>";
$send_mail =  mb_send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

but when i try to run it. display error

`HTTP ERROR 500`

i check into the error_log the problem is this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_language() in
```

how do i fix this. please help.

Comment: Check what the error log has to say. That is _always_ the first thing to do, when you get a 500, and it is not immediately obvious why.

Comment: yes. i already check. the error is "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_language() in...." how do i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `php72-mbstring`.

This can be done by running `sudo yum install -y php72-mbstring`.

After you run this you will want to reload/restart your apache server for the php module to be enabled.

You can do this by running `service httpd restart`